# Checkbox inline with dropdown option

Tags: html, checkbox, html-lists, dropdown

I am trying to position a checkbox on the right side of a dropdown

```
<li>
   <a class="drop-option" data-toggle="tab" href="#bizq">Business</a>
   <input type="checkbox" value="" style="display: inline; float: right">
</li>
```

What I'm trying to have is the checkbox be a separate entity from the actual option itself. So that when I click on the option it goes to a page, and when I toggle the checkbox it does something else.

Essentially the goal is to have multiple pages with iframes. Each time I go to a page it load the iframe. If the checkbox is checked then the iframe can be persistent instead of getting destroyed each time a page is switched.

Should look something like this: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***when I click on the option it goes to a page, and when I toggle the checkbox it does something else.***

This can be implemented by following steps:

1. Add event listener to the *option* element.
2. When *option* element is clicked, check whether user clicks the checkbox inside the *option*. If it is the checkbox clicked, do nothing. Otherwise, go to step 3.
3. Check the current *option* element's checkbox status. Do different things according to different checkbox status.

Here is a code snippet:

```js
var $option = $('a.option');
$option.on('click', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($target.hasClass('toggle')) {
    // checkbox clicked.
    return;
  }
  var childToggle = $this.find('input.toggle').prop('checked');
  var label = $this.find('.label').text();
  if (childToggle) {
    alert('Page ' + label + ' clicked, WITH checkbox checked.');
  } else {
    alert('Page ' + label + ' clicked, WITHOUT checkbox checked.');
  }

});
```

```css
ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}
a.option {
  background: darkcyan;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
a.option input.toggle {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="option">
      <span class="label">Business</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" value="isSelected">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="option">
      <span class="label">Tech</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" value="isSelected">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```